# Azure AD B2C: Setting the Access/ID token renewal rate to 5 minutes causes the application to continually refresh

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Azure AD B2C:

Setting the Access/ID token renewal rate to 5-9 minutes in Azure AD B2C policies under Token Lifetimes in "Token, session, & SSO config" causes our application to continually refresh.  We're using the msal.js library. What causes this? Setting it to 10 minutes works as expected.

Comment: When you say refresh, is it refreshing the page? Or is the token getting refreshed because it is constantly "expired"?